Do something positive for Italian.SE and have a new look for your avatar
Winter Bash 2020 has just begun. This is an old tradition of Stack Exchange sites, which is done for fun, but I also see it as an opportunity to increase participation in our site, something that I think it's really necessary: participation has decreased a lot in the last few months.
For example, you can simply have a look to our question page on our main site or on our Meta site, you can ask or answer questions, write five posts which are interesting enough to have a positive score, help to clear our review queues, suggest an edit to some post, join our community as a new user, start a discussion on our Meta site and perform other actions that give rise to secret hats.
On this page you can see the hats we have earned as a community (but, please, take into account that there are some users of the site which have participated and don't want to have hats, something that it's perfectly OK for me). As you can see, there are also "secret hats" that you can earn participating in some way, but we don't know how. Well, there are some people that have fun trying to discover how to obtain these secret hats.
So, I would like to invite you to try to do something to increase participation, both on the main site and on the Meta site and, if you like this idea, earn some "hats" and have some fun these days by having some changes of look in your Italian.SE user avatar.
